# ExtractBiggestBlob crop cordinates

Tags: aforge

I use ExtractBiggestBlob to minimize my original image to smallest possible contour. And I do this only after binarize the original Image so that I can get smallest possible contour of my image. How can I find the coordinates of the blob after using ExtractBiggestBlob so that I can use that to crop from the original image?

EDIT 1:
I have found it out:

> ```
> ExtractBiggestBlob BBB = new ExtractBiggestBlob();// Extract the biggest Blob
>                     Bitmap biggestBlobsImage = BBB.Apply(ChannelImage);
>                     IntPoint blobPosition = BBB.BlobPosition;
>                     //Console.WriteLine(blobPosition.X);
>                     //Console.WriteLine(blobPosition.Y);
> ```

Comment: Please show the code you have come up with so far.

Comment: I have found it out, Thank you, I am trying to figure out how to get the total of all pixel intensities of an Image now.